# How could I use the Recursion function to push array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the recursion function to push the data in the tempList, however no matter how to fix the code still is an empty array.

```
let tempList=[]
var getWineList =  function(database_name,locaDataBase){
    return new Promise(async (sucess,fail)=>{


        wineList(0,database_name)
        console.log(tempWineList)
        sucess("a")
    })
}

function wineList(currentPosition,database_name){

    let wines= db.collection(database_name)
    .skip(currentPosition)
    wines.get()
        .then((res)=>{


            // tempList.forEach(function(wine,index){
            //  tempWineList.push(wine)
            // })

            if(res.data.length<20){
                console.log(res.data)
                return res.data

            }
            tempWineList.push(res.data)
            return tempList.push(wineList(currentPosition+20,database_name))
        })


}
```

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Provide more clarification. However, you don't need recursion to push array's entries inside another array.

Comment: From where are you calling your `getWineList` method? Are you on the same scope where `tempList` defined? Make sure that this line `tempList.push(wineList(currentPosition+20,database_name))` being called.

Answer (score 0):

Method `wines.get()` is asynchronous. It means, that it don't returns value immediately, but it only returns a promise - promise that it will return value in future. In your code you push to an array inside `then`, so it won't be executed immediately, but when promise will be resolved,  but inside `getWineList` function you don't wait for it to happen and execute `console.log` before that data is pushed.

So the solution is to return promise from `wineList` function and wait before doing console log. You can do it in 2 ways: by `then()` or `async`/`await`

Example of using `async`/`await`:

```
let tempList=[]
var getWineList =  async function(database_name,locaDataBase){
    await wineList(0,database_name)
    console.log(tempWineList)
    return "a";
}

function wineList(currentPosition,database_name){

    let wines = db.collection(database_name)
    .skip(currentPosition);

    let res = await wines.get();

    if(res.data.length<20){
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
    }
    tempWineList.push(res.data)
    return tempList.push(wineList(currentPosition+20,database_name))
})
```

}